# How to Dynamically Fetch Files with WebPack and Exclude Directories (node_modules)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, storybook, lerna

> TL;DR - We have ran into an issue with Storybook inside of a Monorepo
>   whose packages are independently versioned where the problem surrounds
>   Storybook running out of memory when it tries to scan for
>   `*.stories.js` due to it scanning every package's `node_modules`
>   directory. `require.context()` doesn't allow for exclusion to the
>   point where it won't scan the `node_modules` directories and we
>   couldn't find a native webpack solution to this problem - nor could we
>   find any existing discussion points around this problem, whose
>   solution wasn't just `require.context('.', true,
>   /^\.\/((?!node_modules).)*\.stories\.js$/)`. We're posting our
>   discovery and potentially solution to see if anyone in the community
>   has had to solve a similar problem, and see if we are missing
>   something/making it harder than it needs to be.

The problem that we are trying to solve for is that Webpack's `require.context()` method does not allow for excluding specific directories from being scanned. For our project set-up, we are utilizing Lerna to manage a monorepo a JavaScript packages that are all independently versioned. Our file tree looks like this:

```
.
├── config
│   └── storybook
└── packages
    └── vue
        └── components
            ├── example-component
            │   ├── node_modules
            │   │   └── ...
            │   ├── test
            │   │   ├── example.stories.js
            │   │   └── index.spec.js
            │   ├── index.vue
            │   └── package.json
            └── example-parent
                ├── example-component-2
                │   ├── node_modules
                │   │   └── ...
                │   ├── test
                │   │   ├── example.stories.js
                │   │   └── index.spec.js
                │   ├── index.vue
                │   └── package.json
                └── example-component-3
                    ├── node_modules
                    │   └── ...
                    ├── test
                    │   ├── example.stories.js
                    │   └── index.spec.js
                    ├── index.vue
                    └── package.json
```

For our storybook configuration, we need to tell Storybook where each of the components' `*.stories.js` file lives. We want/need the solution to be dynamic in a sense where if we add a new component into the directory tree in the same fashion, Storybook should automatically find the new `*.stories.js` without having to update Storybook's config file.

The option that Storybook suggests, is to use the `require.context(String directory, boolean isDeep, RegEx fileMatch)` method that is a part of webpack. However, when `isDeep` is set as `true` you are unable to restrict the method from scanning particular directories, like `node_modules`, due to the fact that the `directory` parameter is a string and not RegEx. Understandably, a regex match for the directory would make this method more expensive. However, it means that even if I set up my method to look like `require.context('.', true, /^\.\/((?!node_modules).)*\.stories\.js$/)` WebPack is still going to traverse my `node_modules` directories but won't match any internal `*.stories.js` files.

This becomes an issue when we use Lerna to install all the packages' depenencies via `lerna bootstrap`. Since by default that command will install ALL dependencies, including devDependencies for stuff like automated tests, an individual `node_modules` directory for a component could be quite large. So as we are adding more and more components, we have ran into a memory issue with running Storybook when components have all of their dependencies installed.

Our initial band-aid solution, was to restrict Lerna from install devDependencies by using `lerna bootstrap -- --production --no-optional` however this makes us unable to run tests. To run tests, we then have to install all dependencies... which means we can't run Storybook until we clean up the `node_modules`.

Our current solution is to use a `fs` type of library/package that allows us to traverse the directory tree with more specificity, and manually ignore `node_modules` when scanning deep directories. This allows us to still nest components within parent directories for better organization of similar components, and still allows Storybook to automatically find new `*.stories.js` files. So now our story discovery and Storybook config looks like:

```js
const path = require('path');
const directoryTree = require('directory-tree');

let isPopulatedDir = (item) => item.type === 'directory' && item.children.length > 0;

let isStoryFile = (item) => item.type === 'file' && /\.stories\.js$/.test(item.name);

function parseChildren(children, response) {
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    let child = children[i];
    if(child.name === 'node_modules') continue;
    if (isPopulatedDir(child)) {
      parseChildren(child.children, response);
    } else if(isStoryFile(child)) {
      response.push(child.path);
    } 
  }
  return response;
}

function getStories() {
  const tree = directoryTree("./packages/vue/components"),
        storyPaths = [];
  tree.children.forEach(item => {
    if (isPopulatedDir(item)) {
      storyPaths.push(...parseChildren(item.children, []));
    }
  });
  return storyPaths;
}

module.exports = {
  stories: getStories(),
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.node = {
      fs: "empty"
    };

    config.resolve.modules = [
      ...(config.resolve.modules || []),
      path.resolve('./'),
    ];

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  }
}
```

This solution works, it doesn't traverse any `node_module` directories, and allow us to dynamically find the `*.stories.js` files, no matter how their directory may be set up. But we can't help but feel like this is a problem that other people have had to of ran into, and maybe we are just overlooking a solution that Webpack already offers. So please, if you have had similar obstacles to overcome whose solution may work better for us we'd love to hear your approach or thoughts on our solution.

Comment: `stories: ['./packages/vue/components/**/!(node_modules)/*.stories.js']` should work but if it's then converted to a webpack require it probably won't help much.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately any regex used in this format gets converted to `require.context('./packages/vue/components', true, /!(node_modules)/*.stories.js/)`